# Blank space in MS Word (Mac)

Tags: microsoft-word, office-for-mac

Does anyone know how I can get rid of the blank space indicated in the image? It's not part of the footer, nor of the footnote and **only** exists on the first page.

[image: MS Word image one]

[image: MS Word image two]

Comment: Check the footer height *and* the bottom margin for the first section in your document. (if the "Different First Page" option is checked for your footer, make sure to check the first page)

Comment: Funnily, "first page different" is not checked. The bottom margin is 2cm (much *more* than the blank space), the footer height is way *less* than the blank space as it can be seen it the picture :(

Comment: Is there more than one section on page 1? If yes, make sure the cursor is at the top of the page before entering the footer

Comment: Probably you have footnotes configured to be below text instead of at the bottom of page and the next paragraph cannot be placed for some reason on the first page. See: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/footnotes-beneath-text-but-would-like-them-at/0859d263-39e3-458b-86b0-b9fae3f5f791